# JavaFX, WebEngine. Как отследить изменения URL

Tags: java, javafx, webview

Есть WebView и кнопка. При нажатии кнопки, выполняется JS

```
webEngine.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"[data-bid='924']\").click()");
```

После нужно выполнить еще один скрипт, НО после того как загрузится след. страница (выполнение первого скрипта переводит на другую страницу).

```
webEngine.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"[href='#placeBet']\").click()");
```

Проблема в том, что второй скрипт выполняется сразу, я пытался это исправить, добавив слушатель:

```
        wenEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
        System.out.println(newState);
        String url = autoBetEngine.getLocation();
        if(url.contains("addBet?")) {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                autoBetEngine.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"[href='#placeBet']\").click()");
            }
        }
    });
```

Но он не срабатывает вообще, когда переходит именно на ту страничку. Это мобильная версия сайта, и там видать как-то иначе переход работает.

Так вот, есть ли какой-то слушатель, который следит за изменением URL WebView или нет? Как мне решить эту проблему? Заранее благодарен за любой совет.

Comment: А тайтл у двух страниц разный?

Comment: Нет. Одинаковый. Я уже костыль написал (: